# How to remove popup malware - sponsorship/bigfintuna/milesandkms

Tags: malware

I have a malware problem similar to the one described [here](http://listserv.syr.edu/scripts/wa.exe?A2=LM_NET;673eb4b0.1309) and [here](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/507762/accidental-click-now-getting-milesandkms-and-longfintuna/)

and I'm looking for information on how to remove it. Spybot Search and Destroy and Malwarebytes Antimalware both give my computer a clean bill of health now. However, when I first encountered problem, a Spybot scan would say there were 4 problems it couldn't resolve.

Then I downloaded and ran Malwarebytes. It claimed to have successfully done something, and after that Spybot found no more problems.

Comment: Reinstall your computer, only way to be sure.

Comment: There are tons of removal tools from reputable sources like AV companies that you can use to make sure its gone. However, in all honesty, when a system is compromised, cleaning it works but ultimately the only 100% assurance you have is to clean install like @LucasKauffman said and be careful "restoring" your files back to the new system, that's how alot of them keep coming back.